# Jenkins build triggered with parametrized trigger plugin is blocked by the job who triggered it

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Following constellation:
Job A triggers job B with parametrized trigger plugin. Job B is triggered but will not start as if it is blocked by something. If job A gets stopped, job B will start and is no longer blocked. Sadly job A needs to wait until job B is finished. Triggering job B with CLI works, but I have no clue how to make job A wait until job B is completed.

There are no jobs that should block job b. Here is a is the relevant part of a hudson.modelQueue log:

```
Queue maintenance started on hudson.model.Queue@620e75e8 with Queue.Snapshot{waitingList=[];blockedProjects=[hudson.model.Queue$BlockedItem:hudson.model.FreeStyleProject@45b9a526[TEST_KAQA-701--FakeCore]:295222];buildables=[];pendings=[]}
```

If anyone knows why Jenkins behaves that way, please explain. I am thankful for any helpful tips on how to further investigate this issue, as I ran out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolution was quite simple, the blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding tag was set true. I have no good answer why i didnt see it myself before asking.

Comment: For a noob like me it took a time to find out this is a Mantis option only visible clicking on Advanced Options in the web configuration page